# iPhone X photo preview different from result

Tags: iphone, photos, preview

I would like to know if the camera behavior I am experiencing it's normal or if there is a problem.

When I shoot a photo in low light conditions the photo "preview" I see in the camera app is really different from the final photo.

This is before taking the photo. As you can see there is some noise in the picture:
[image: before]

This is the result taken from the camera roll. The noise is not present anymore and light is totally different:
[image: after]

How it is supposed to work? Because if the preview it's different from the result I cannot trust the preview and maybe I can do some adjustment before shooting (e.g. change the exposure) that will led to a completely unexpected result.

Comment: Even expensive DSLRs do the same on the preview screen. It's not a complete representation of the final image, it is a quick scan with lighting levels compressed so you can see what the framing is like.

Answer (score 1):

The final photo is not a “screenshot”-esque result, but a processed image.

Comment: I totally understand that it's processed, but if the result it's so distant from the preview (see the light) how can I make adjustment before shooting?

Comment: You can only do that post-production (in “Edit”), or use a third party app to shoot in raw to have full control